# PHP 7 - RecursiveArrayIterator Trying to construct a drop down menu using a multi-dimensional array with string and array values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, twitter-bootstrap-3, iteration

PHP 7

- Intermediate to beginner level coder.

I have researched around pretty thoroughly and unable to find a solution on SO that fits my issue completely. I found very similar, but just different enough so I am unable to make it work out.

I am trying to construct a nav bar in Bootstrap 3 using results from a DB query. The results have a mix of string values along with array values. I have worked out most of the construct, but I am unable to get the child array values to insert into and display the results into the drop down menu properly. I am using the `RecursiveArrayIterator` function with `->getChilden()` to filter out the arrays and show the `->hasChildren()` values.

**PROBLEM:**

My drop down lists are only displaying the word `array`, they are not parsing in the value of the array.

The drop down is also getting all array values that are a child and placing them in both buttons, at least that is what I think is happening.

Here is what I want the menu to look like:
[Link to Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/72vEqGxY65)

I am able to get the structure perfect for the navbar and parent elements, the drop down works, however, I am getting 'array' results in the drop down, I am also getting a combination of both array results as I have yet to figure out how to filter out the arrays with children to parse the proper info to the proper arrays drop down section.

Here is a screen shot:
[image: Screen shot of browser results]

*Here is the DB query in array:
Only two arrays are coming from this query, `CUSTOMERS` and `CUST_ROUTE_DAY`
**$custRouteDay** and **$custName** are variables from a while loop of the fetch_assoc() results.

```
define("CUST_ROUTE_DAY", $custRouteDay);
define("CUSTOMERS", $custName);
define("NAVBTNS", [
    "Customers"=>CUSTOMERS,
    "Route Info"=>CUST_ROUTE_DAY,
    "Tasks",
    "Networking",
    "Maps"
]);
```

Here is the resulting array that comes from the DB.

```
NAVBTNS = Array ( [Customers] => Array ( [0] => John Banner [1] => Dale 
Landry [2] => Bill Childers [3] => Darren Little ) [Route Info] => Array ( 
[0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 ) Tasks Networking Maps )
```

Basically there are two functions, one to construct the `navbar` and another to construct the `drop down buttons`.

```
function construct_navbar_buttons(){
$navbtns = NAVBTNS;
$iterator = new RecursiveArrayIterator($navbtns);
$btns = '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">';
$i = 0;
while ($iterator->valid()) {
    if ($iterator->hasChildren()) {
        $btnNm = array();
        //Get the names for the dropdown (Arrays) which, for the  
        //arrays will = the $key value and place them into $btnNm[]
        foreach(NAVBTNS as $btnName=>$result){
            $btnNm[]=$btnName;
            $results[]=$result;
        }
        $btns .= '<li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="">
                        <i class="'.NAVICONS[$i].'">
</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$btnNm[$i].'&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="caret">&nbsp;</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">';
        //Get the values within the child arrays            
        foreach($row = $iterator->getChildren() as $key => $btn){
            $count = count($row);
            for($inc=1;$inc<$count;$inc++){ 
                $btns .= '<li><a href="?p='.$i.'">'.$results[$i].'</a></li>';
            }   
        }       
        $btns .= '</ul>
                    </li>';
    }else{          
        foreach($iterator as $num => $value){
            if(!is_array($value)){
                $btns .= '<li><a href="?p='.$i.'">'.$value.'</a></li>';
            }
        }                   
    }
    $i++;
    $iterator->next();
}

$btns .= '</ul>';
return $btns;
}

function construct_navbar(){
$stmt = '
<!--NAV BAR IS TOP FIXED-->
<nav role="navigation" class="'.STYLE["fixed-top"].'">

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Pool Buddy Pro</a>
        </div>';


$stmt .= construct_navbar_buttons();
$stmt .= '

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <i class="caret"></i></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i> Edit User Account Info</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Search Customers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View Your Network</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Logout</a></li>
                    <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
   </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>';
 return $stmt;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <?php echo construct_navbar(); ?>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:50px;padding-left:0px;" class="row">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse col-lg-4"> 
                <div style="box-shadow:1px 0px 4px #999;background-color:#F8F8F8;padding-top:20px !important;" class="col-lg-12 sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <?php construct_side_bar_customer_nav(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="heading col-lg-12">
                    ...CONTENT...
                </div>  
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

So very close, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: RecursiveArrayIterator is to try filter which entries have children or not. 
The $row is used to find the static number of 'hasChildren()' so I can use that count to place the values of the children results in the drop down list-item.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I have two arrays nested in the parent array. Honestly, I am trying to make it so that it is all created dynamically. So if there are nested arrays, it creates the structure and then places the proper values in the menu structure.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions `$btnNm[]=$btnName` is holding the value of the name for the parent level drop down button. I pass the variable into the foreach loop and increment it with $i

Comment: I have found the issue from what `ARRAY` comes, you do `"Customers"=>CUSTOMERS,` but later `foreach(NAVBTNS as $btnName=>$result)` and then `$results[]=$result;` (here you have an array in $result `CUSTOMERS`) and later then `$results[$i]` produces the `ARRAY` output, because `$results[$i]` is then `CUSTOMERS` array. fix that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better apporach to iterate here.

- You have an array with stringvalues OR subarrays

So do

```
//this 2 arrays can created just once, content never changes
foreach(NAVBTNS as $btnName=>$result){
     $btnNm[]=$btnName;
     $results[]=$result;
}
//$iterator=$navbtns
foreach($iterator as $k => $v){//$k holds index or e.g. Customers  
   //You can use $k here for the <i></i> tag 
   if(is_array($v)){//go over subarray
         $btns .= '<li class="dropdown">....</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$k.'&nbsp;&nbsp;';
         foreach($v as $key => $value){
            //do stuff example data: [0] => John Banner
             $btns .= '<li><a href="?p='.$key.'">'.$value.'</a></li>';
         }
         $btns .= "</ul>\n</li>";
   } else {//whe have a string value
       //do stuff  example data: Tasks  - key here seems aways a index number 
       $btns .= '<li><a href="?p='.$k.'">'.$v.'</a></li>';
   }
}
```

More is not needed, because you will never get an array->sub-array->sub-sub-array.

I have problems to get the logic of `?p='.$i.'` here.

Comment: Your suggestion works perfectly with a little tweak. I simply added the proper UL before `foreach`, LI/A/UL starting and the closing UL tag and kept the $i to increment `NAVICONS[$i]` to get the right bootstrap class for the different button as the $key value is a mixed array/string value. 

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: @dalelandry Always nice to help :-)

Comment: @dalelandry You should open a new question for that. And not dropping all code into the comments :-) Btw, you can not use `array_search` like that. You can only give on search string as parameter. It is not possible to use `||` here.